# How to use chunkCompleted() to process large elements in XML

Tags: php, xml, xmlstreamer

I'm evaluating the [XmlStreamer](https://github.com/prewk/XmlStreamer) class to process potentially large XML files. It works great with tiny files but as soon as I feed it with a large XML file it eats all the system memory and hits whatever `memory_limit` I set (even though I still haven't written code to *use* the data).

As far as I can tell, it loops through the top level nodes (excluding the root element) and makes a call to `processNode()` when it finishes reading each one. The callback function receives a string with the complete XML string of the node and that seems to be the only way to access the data. (The provided example suggests parsing it with `SimpleXML`.) This approach will clearly fail as soon as a top level node contains several MB worth of data, as it's my case.

So the class allows to override `chunkCompleted()` «to improve performance». It seems to be exactly what I need—but I can't figure out how to use it for something useful.

The class calls `chunkCompleted()` at regular intervals but I can't figure out how to access partially read data. The callback doesn't receive parameters, all class properties are private, there aren't methods I can call. The [example given](https://github.com/prewk/XmlStreamer#advanced-example) populates custom properties at `processNode()` and reads them back from `chunkCompleted()` but that's pretty pointless: you will not have data available until the complete top-level node has been processed and loaded into memory. All calls to `chunkCompleted()` will do nothing except the last one, and in that case I could have done my stuff directly at `processNode()`.

Furthermore, if I reduce the chunk size the class starts missing nodes, suggesting that it cannot process elements that don't fit in a single chunk.

Am I missing something obvious or the library is just not production ready?

```php
class FirstExample extends XmlStreamer{
    public function processNode($xmlString, $elementName, $nodeIndex){
        echo __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
        var_dump($xmlString, $elementName, $nodeIndex);
    }

    public function chunkCompleted(){
        echo __METHOD__ . PHP_EOL;
    }
}

$xml = new FirstExample('/path/to/my.xml', 80);
if( $xml->parse() ){
    echo 'OK' . PHP_EOL;
}else{
    echo 'Error' . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Comment: Have you considered using the built-in (with the XML functions) [XMLReader](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/class.xmlreader.php) class instead of userland code?  It may perform better, though with a more annoying level of difficulty...

Comment: @Charles Yes, I've used `XMLReader` in the past—it's powerful and has a nice performance. I'm trying out this library to find out if it can be an alternative for simple tasks.